# Symfony: how to place a specific item in first position with query_builder option?

Tags: forms, symfony

In a form, I use an **EntityType** field, which allows selection of several items from entity **Member**. I am sending the id of a specific member to my form through the form's option (a variable named `$selfId`) and would like to use the `query_builder` function to return a list of members where this specific member would appear in first position. How could I achieve this? I'm using Symfony 3.

I'm thinking of something like this:

```
->add('members',    EntityType::class, array(
        'required'      => true,
        'label'         => 'Members',
        'class'         => 'AppBundle:Member',
        'multiple'      => true,
        'query_builder' => function (MemberRepository $er) use ($selfId) {
                                $qb = $er->createQueryBuilder('m');
                                return $qb
                                          ->orderBy('m.id = :selfId') // invented code!!!!!!!
                                          ->setParameter('selfId', $selfId)
                                          ;
                            }
        ))
;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an item you can add to the code above item called preferred_choices that should do what you are asking

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#preferred-choices

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The option preferred_choices can help **display** some choices in first position, but won't actually change the options order as I need. Furthermore, to use preferred_choices, I should know the index value of the choice I want to put in firts position, but I only know its Id, as it is an entity.